# Latest Graphviz for Windows

Tags: windows, graphviz

I found the latest Graphviz source code on https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz but where can I download the latest Windows installer?

Comment: Please note that on this site we recommend *software which meets given requirements* – not download sources for X.

Answer (score 0):

The latest official stable release should be available from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html *(found by following the Download link at http://graphviz.org/ not too unsurprisingly*.

If you need the **very latest** successful build you can fetch it from AppVeyor by going to [the build history](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ellson/graphviz-pl238/history) finding the latest build from "master" with a green bar to the left *(indicating a successful build)* clicking on it, selecting the configuration you desire, (I suggest a release build), then selecting "Artifacts".

Comment: Steve, do you know where I can D/L a portable Windows version? Developers don't have admin rights here :-(

Comment: @Mawg - There is Viz.js which is a javascript port of GraphViz https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/ _describes itself as a hack_ and is used by d3-vraphviz https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz. There is also Dagre https://github.com/dagrejs that looks promising. Chocolaty also has a graphviz portabble https://chocolatey.org/packages/graphviz.portable & so does portatble apps https://portableapps.com/node/38245 (both requires some other downloads but can potentially run from a USB key.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I am just looking for command line, so the JS is out. I can't install Chocolatey for the same reason that I can't install Graphviz :-) I will raise a request to IT via my manager; maybe I'll have it by xmas

Comment: You could use the Portable Apps option _(either from a local dir or a USB key)_ the only point is that to run the apps easily you need to run from the portable apps command line.

Comment: I could, if IT hadn't blocked the site :-/  Thanks, though (+1)

Comment: To make matters worse, there ***is*** [a portable version](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html) on the GraphViz site. I just D?Led it at home, but at work it looks like the ZIP is corrupt :-(

Comment: @Mawg - Just tried downloading the zip from the same site and 7z opens it fine. Extracting the release folder lets me run the bin\dot.exe tool so it looks fine to me.